# Linear Constant-Coefficient ordinary differential equation - complex roots - please check my reasoning

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would appreciate it if someone could please check my reasoning for the following differential equation problem. I'm specifically concerned about the last part, since the equation becomes too long for me to check manually. Thank you.

I have the differential equation $y'' + 4y' + 5y = 0$.

It has roots $r = -2 \pm i$.

Therefore, the general solution is:

$y = C_1 e^{ (-2 + i)x } + C_2e^{(-2 - i)x}$

$ \Rightarrow y = e^{-2x} (C_1 e^{ix} + C_2e^{-xi})$

Euler's formula is $e^{ix} = (\cos(x) + i\sin(x))$. Since we have the terms $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-xi}$, we can use Euler's formula:

$e^{ix} = (\cos(x) + i\sin(x))$

$e^{-xi} = (\cos(-x) + i\sin(-x))$

$\therefore y = e^{-2x} (C_1(\cos(x) + i\sin(x)) + C_2(\cos(-x) + i\sin(-x)))$

Given that $ y = e^{-2x} (C_1(\cos(x) + i\sin(x)) + C_2(\cos(-x) + i\sin(-x)))$, we can conclude that $y'' + 4y' + 5y = 0$, had we taken the time to take the second and first derivatives of $y$, and cancel out all of the terms.

Comment: Your last $y$ is Ok. Is there anything else  that you wanted to know?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that (1) my overall reasoning is correct, and (2) specifically the last statement is correct. So everything is correct?

Comment: Just note that $\cos(x)$ is an even function and $\sin(x)$ is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is that you have found a (general solution) to your given 2nd order ODE and you want to check your answer to see if it is correct without calculating the first and second derivatives of your answer. In order to prove (check) your function is indeed a solution (ie that you have carried out the method correctly) you have no choice except to evaluate the second and first derivatives of your answer and then check that your second derivative plus 4 times your first derivative  plus 5 times your function does give you (the) zero (function).

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I was hoping that someone could verify my reasoning, since doing it manually would be difficult and timely.

Comment: It can be time consuming BUT sometimes seeing your function has certain properties means that the calculation of the derivatives can be achieved "quicker".

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Okay here is a possibility. So a function is called even if $f(-x)=f(x)$ for $x$ in the domain. An example is the cosine function (though there are lots of others). A function is called odd if $f(-x)= -f(x)$. An example is the sine function.  Using these properties you can often simplify a complicated function and reduce the number of derivatives you need to find. ( You will meet this idea more when you do "Fourier Series" where using odd and even functions plays a role in calculating what are called the "Fourier coefficients")